# form top image resizes and don't stable in all screen sizes

Tags: android, xml, image, layout

i'm working on application that have top image in all forms.
i designed the image correctly but to be in top i should set scale type= "fitstart" to be truly be in top.
but the problem is when screen rotates or when app run in bigger screen the image wont stretch in horizon. i think my problem is the  imageview size. and it's not just in size of my image and it have blank top and buttons.

how i can solve this problem and what should be the image property. with regards

[image: this is the currect one]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to maintain your images in different folders in

```
res/drawable-mdpi/your_image.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/your_image.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/your_image.png       // bitmap for extra high density

small   Resources for small size screens.
normal  Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)
large   Resources for large size screens.
xlarge  Resources for extra large size screens.
```

**And make sure "adjust view bounds"=true in your xml**

follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more deatils

Comment: i know about that. but my problem is i can't stretch image horizontally with keep aspect raito. :(

Comment: For that you need to mention this in your manifest file at
<activity
android:name="com.package.YourActivity"            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

Comment: hi, it's seems that i have this problem in all my projects. in some layout works and in some wont. my problem is as you know i wanna stretch my image for all sized screens with keep aspect ratio. like my title image that must keep whole top part of screen. :(